# Is Xamarin.Forms the right tools to use on application with heavy use of f.ex TTS, OCR, voices etc?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

We are planning our first applications on tablets, to run on both iOS, Android and Windows.

We are considering using Xamaring.Forms.

Our applications must be able to access several functions/feature on the devices.
F.ex: OCR, TTS (text-to-speech), installed voiced, use our own installed voices, use our own c++ libraries

Anyone with experience with similar application using Xamarin.Forms?
- Performance, will it work smooth?
- Overhead
- complexity
- UI issues?
- Other issues

Or will native application for each platform be a better alternative?

Any idea/comment/recommendation?

Comment: Take this from personal experience: If you're going to be doing a lot of custom drawing (Custom UI), go with native xamarin, instead of Forms. There is a performance penalty to using Xamarin Forms, and if you're barely going to be using the whole "Write UI once, run everywhere" concept, it's a complete waste of both developer time, and device performance. You're going to spent time fighting the framework, and the device is gonna use more performance because of the layers between Forms and Native. However if you're going to be using native UI; it's a pretty good choice.

Answer (score 1):

As the team lead of Xamarin.Forms, I also suggest in your case you go with Xamarin platform. You would be basically in the sweet spot for maximal codeshare with minimal pain for a Xamarin platform (non-Forms) project.

If you used forms you would be doing too much DI and custom rendering from the sound of it to actually benefit dramatically.

Comment: thanks for quick answer :-)
Question: with DI you mean?

Comment: DI= Dependency Injection. This means that you have to write an interface for the common PCL project with iOS and Android specific implementations.